# Can't check checkbox in Datawindow

Tags: wpf, powerbuilder, datawindow

Can I know why the checkbox in Datawindow can't be checked. I have changed the column style to `checkbox`.

I am using PB.Net version 12.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the following properties of the column?

- is not protected (Protect = 0)
- its taborder is not 0 (positive)

Also the datawindow has to be:

- enabled
- NOT readonly

Br. Gábor

Ps.: If you need more details how to check/set this please let me know

Comment: Thanks for your response,but the new problem is the value of right text changed whenever I checked and Unchecked checkbox. When I checked, the right text will changed to 1 and 0 for unchecked. I have set Protected=False, Override Edit=true, Value for Off=0, value for On=1, and Taborder=10.